# Minimum frame rate after merging the same MP4 files

Tags: ffmpeg

Recently I'm trying to merge some split movies in MP4 format. Found the lossless merging of a movie and its copy using ffmpeg. This has no practical meaning, the purpose is to ensure that the format of the two videos is consistent. Use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i filelist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

The strange thing is that the minimum frame rate is not a fixed value, and it is not consistent with the original video.

Why is this? What method can be used to achieve merging without loss?

Comment: Hello, did you ensure that the split parts all have desired FPS? How was it split exactly?